# Можно ли ContentProvider использовать с относительными ссылками

Tags: android, java

Использую его в WebView для ссылок на все подключаемые файлы(css, js, jpeg....)
Путь выглядит следующим образом:

```
content://com.example/images/qq.jpeg
```

или

```
content://com.example/script/ss.jj
```

Можно ли сделать так, что бы ContentProvider воспринимал относительный путь:
/images/qq.jpeg и /script/ss.jj , что бы так задавать ссылки на все файлы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Способ расшифровки `Uri` задается `ContentResolver`'ом. Из контекста вашего вопроса непонятно вы используете стандартный `ContentResolver` или свой самописный? Если свой самописный, то настроить его на дешифровки по относительному пути будет просто, а иначе тут надо уже понимать как работает встроенный.